# CA1811 Error not being Displayed when I Think It Should be

Tags: c#, fxcop

I try to find unused methods in my database layer, cause I just copied it from the old project and check what I still need and what not. But fxcop doesn't display the expected errors. There are several methods, that are not called, but they are not listed.

I changed all the methods from public to internal, but it still doesn't display the errors.

The class has the following structure:

```
namespace mynamspace {
    public partial class WebsiteModel {
        static ILog log = LogManager.GetLogger(typeof(WebsiteModel));

        manyunusedmethods
    }
}
```

Had anybody else this problem? The other part of WebsiteModel is of the type `DbContext`

**EDIT** I tried a few things, and it seems like it never shows the error CA1811. What am I doing wrong?

My ruleset file looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RuleSet Name="Coding Lizards fxcop ruleset" Description="Dieser Regelsatz enthält alle Regeln. Das Ausführen dieses Regelsatzes führt möglicherweise zu einer hohen Anzahl gemeldeter Warnungen. Verwenden Sie diesen Regelsatz, um einen Überblick über alle Probleme in Ihrem Code zu erhalten. Dies kann Ihnen bei der Entscheidung behilflich sein, welche der spezifischeren Regelsätze für Ihre Projekte am besten geeignet sind." ToolsVersion="11.0">
  <IncludeAll Action="Warning" />
  <Rules AnalyzerId="Microsoft.Analyzers.ManagedCodeAnalysis" RuleNamespace="Microsoft.Rules.Managed">
    <Rule Id="CA1811" Action="Error" />
    <Rule Id="CA1823" Action="Error" />
    <Rule Id="CA1804" Action="Error" />
    <Rule Id="CA1801" Action="Error" />
  </Rules>
</RuleSet>
```

Comment: FYI, you are using the word "throw" incorrectly, which may be why there's now a close vote on this question. Exceptions are thrown. CA1811 is an error, which should be displayed, not thrown.

Comment: BTW, I am not surprised that FxCop can't show you this problem. I'm not certain it can do so except for `private` methods. On the other hand, ReSharper can certainly show you, if you use their "Solution Wide Analysis" feature. It will show you whether there is any code in the solution which uses the methods (unless they are part of the implementation of an interface, for instance).

Comment: It didn't even showed the the unused private method. ReSharper I don't want to use, cause it has no free version  Shouldn't fxcop be able to show all not used methods that are internal or private?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It works for me on VS2013 with the following custom ruleset:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RuleSet Name="Uncalled Private Code" Description="Custom Ruleset" ToolsVersion="12.0">
  <Rules AnalyzerId="Microsoft.Analyzers.ManagedCodeAnalysis" RuleNamespace="Microsoft.Rules.Managed">
    <Rule Id="CA1811" Action="Error" />
  </Rules>
</RuleSet>
```

[image: CA1811 in action]

Comment: Hm… I use VS2012 and it doesn't work. Could you try it with an ASP.net MVC4 Razor project?

Comment: Is the code accessing some fields or properties? As far as I can see the analysis is somewhat flaky in a Web Application project. It doesn't recognize properly when the method is inside a controller, is not static or does access properties...

Comment: That might be it, the code is in a controller and in the model. And yes it does access properties and yes it is not static. The problem is, if I just extract all the stuff in an external library, I can't check because it is then public. Thats annoying -.-